# Send parameter to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently sitting on a macbook, and therefore i'm using Terminal. Anyway, I have created an adventure game in a file called adventure.py. The thing I want to do is to send a parameter to that file, for example:

1. -h/ --help That explains what parameters that work
2. -i/ --info Gives a description of the game
3. -v/ --version Gives the version of the game
4. -c/ --cheat Gives out cheats for the game or a explanation of how to complete the game as fast as possible.

What i'm guessing it that in terminal you write: adventure.py --version for example. But I dont know how to get started with this or how to even implement this. I've tried to google for an answer but havent found anything.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) - it's a Python package for doing exactly this. Examples, etc. are all in the documentation.

Comment: That's exactly what the dupe answer is.